# Problem with plot of age pyramid in R, blue lines

Tags: r

i got problem with my plot of age pyramid in R.It's all going good, but there are blue lines in the background and values are in strange format. I don't have any idea what's going on, becouse there's no option to format it anywhere and i have to remove that.

```
    install.packages("pyramid")
library(pyramid)




d=data.frame("mezczyzni"=c(4432,4446,3512,4086,6046,5961,8272,7581,6376,5431,5595,6871,6608,4810,8197),
"kobiety"=c(4314,4320,3511,3705,5298,5948,7966,7429,6190,5574,5822,7733,7962,6161,13235),
"Wiek"=c("0-4","4-9","10-14","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34","35-39","40-44","45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65-69","70+"))


d

pyramid(d,Laxis=seq(0,15000,len=5), Raxis=seq(0,15000,len=5), 
 AxisFM="g", AxisBM="", AxisBI=3, Cgap=0.3, Cstep=1, Csize=1, 
 Llab="Mężczyźni", Rlab="Kobiety", Clab="Wiek", GL=TRUE, Cadj=-0.03, 
 Lcol="Cyan", Rcol="Pink", Ldens=-1, Rdens=-1,main="Piramida wieku powiatu m. Gliwice w roku 2015")






x=c(4229,5157,6516,8927,9810,7584,6429,6703,8134,8874,7382,4964,4840,3968,5500)
y=c(3901,4912,6275,8580,8861,7474,6286,6653,8648,9463,8034,5448,5574,4866,10183)

a=data.frame("x"=x,"y"=y,"wiek"=c("0-4","4-9","10-14","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34","35-39","40-44","45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65-69","70+"))
a

pyramid(a,Laxis=seq(0,15000,len=5), Raxis=seq(0,15000,len=5), 
 AxisFM="g", AxisBM="", AxisBI=3, Cgap=0.3, Cstep=1, Csize=1, 
 Llab="Mężczyźni", Rlab="Kobiety", Clab="Wiek", GL=TRUE, Cadj=-0.03, 
 Lcol="Yellow", Rcol="Green", Ldens=-1, Rdens=-1,main="Piramida wieku powiatu m. Gliwice w roku 2001")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AxisFM` argument controls the formatting of the x-axis. Try "fg" of "s" to prevent scientific notation.

For the blue dotted lines, change `GL` to FALSE.

```
pyramid(d,Laxis=seq(0,15000,len=5), Raxis=seq(0,15000,len=5), 
        AxisFM="fg", AxisBM="", AxisBI=3, Cgap=0.3, Cstep=1, Csize=1, 
        Llab="Mężczyźni", Rlab="Kobiety", Clab="Wiek", GL=FALSE, Cadj=-0.03,  
        Lcol="Cyan", Rcol="Pink", Ldens=-1, Rdens=-1,main="Piramida wieku powiatu m. Gliwice w roku 2015")
```

[image]

Comment: Good job, yeah the `GL` option stands for Grid Lines, i assume the axisFM stands for Format maybe?

Comment: @DanielJachetta. Yeah, presumably. The argument names are a little non-conformist, although the package author has done a pretty good job otherwise. Not many packages can claim to have a function that can create population pyramids.